# Find/replace in Keynote with Applescript

Tags: replace, find, applescript, keynote

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to automate a find/replace function in Keynote 6.2.

My goal is to find/replace in the entire document. I have text from the clipboard that I want to replace a string with.

The closest I've come is a script on this page, but it doesn't work in Keynote 6.2.

http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=26603

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Just did this based on adjusting what you linked to to work with my v6.2.2 of Keynote. Hopefully this gets you started (note the examples in the AppleScript dictionary of Keynote):

```
tell application "Keynote"
    tell document 1
        set slidebody to object text of default body item of current slide
        set slidebody to my searchnreplace("foo", "BEE", slidebody)
        set object text of default body item of slide 1 to slidebody
        set slidetitle to object text of default title item of current slide
        set slidetitle to my searchnreplace("foo", "AAK", slidetitle)
        set object text of default title item of slide 1 to slidetitle
    end tell
end tell

-- I am a very old search & replace function...
on searchnreplace(searchstr, replacestr, txt)
    considering case, diacriticals and punctuation
        if txt contains searchstr then
            set olddelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {searchstr}
            set txtitems to text items of txt
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {replacestr}
            set txt to txtitems as Unicode text
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to olddelims
        end if
    end considering
    return txt
end searchnreplace
```

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

**[EDIT]**
To do text items in your keynote project (as opposed to 'title objects' or 'body objects'), you can do the following (note that this is case-sensitive, and that, of course, to do multiple items you'll make a repeat loop):

```
tell application "Keynote"
    tell document 1
        set textObjectText to object text of text item 1 of current slide
        set adjustedText to my searchnreplace("Foo", "BEE", textObjectText)
        set object text of text item 1 of slide 1 to adjustedText
    end tell
end tell

-- I am the same very old search & replace function...
on searchnreplace(searchstr, replacestr, txt)
    considering case, diacriticals and punctuation
        if txt contains searchstr then
            set olddelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {searchstr}
            set txtitems to text items of txt
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {replacestr}
            set txt to txtitems as Unicode text
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to olddelims
        end if
    end considering
    return txt
end searchnreplace
```

Before and after:

[image]

[image]

**[EDIT TWO]**

The following code asks user for search and replace strings (using two dialogs), and replaces every occurrence of every text item with the replaced version. Weirdly, it includes `default body item` and `default title item` but does not alter the text (in order to do that, you'd have to use a variation of the example I first showed).

```
tell application "Keynote"
    activate
    set q1 to display dialog "Enter Search String:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK..."} default button 2
    set s to (text returned of q1)
    set q2 to display dialog "Enter Replace String:" default answer s buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2
    set r to (text returned of q2)


    tell document 1
        set ii to (count of text items of current slide)
        set textItemmax to ii
        repeat with i from 1 to textItemmax by 1
            set textObjectText to (object text of text item i of current slide) as text
            set adjustedText to my searchnreplace(s, r, textObjectText)
            set object text of text item i of current slide to adjustedText
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell

-- I am the same very old search & replace function...
on searchnreplace(searchstr, replacestr, txt)
    considering case, diacriticals and punctuation
        if txt contains searchstr then
            set olddelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {searchstr}
            set txtitems to text items of txt
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {replacestr}
            set txt to txtitems as Unicode text
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to olddelims
        end if
    end considering
    return txt
end searchnreplace
```

**[EDIT THREE]**
This will cycle through slides and text items (I really hope this gets you to where you want):

```
tell application "Keynote"
    activate
    set q1 to display dialog "Enter Search String:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK..."} default button 2
    set s to (text returned of q1)
    set q2 to display dialog "Enter Replace String:" default answer s buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2
    set r to (text returned of q2)


    set slideMax to (count of slides of document 1)
    repeat with slideIndex from 1 to slideMax by 1
        set ii to (count of text items of slide slideIndex of document 1)
        set textItemmax to ii
        repeat with i from 1 to textItemmax by 1
            set textObjectText to (object text of text item i of slide slideIndex of document 1)
            set adjustedText to my searchnreplace(s, r, textObjectText as text)
            set object text of text item i of slide slideIndex of document 1 to (adjustedText as text)
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell


-- I am the same very old search & replace function...
on searchnreplace(searchstr, replacestr, txt)
    considering case, diacriticals and punctuation
        if txt contains searchstr then
            set olddelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {searchstr}
            set txtitems to text items of txt
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {replacestr}
            set txt to txtitems as Unicode text
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to olddelims
        end if
    end considering
    return txt
end searchnreplace
```

Comment: I've tried this and nothing seems to happen. I should point out that I want to search/replace ALL instances of the text in the document -- not just the current slide. Also, I'm not really interested in the title per se -- ANY instance of the text should be changed. Can I target that effectively?

Comment: You'll have to repeat loop through the slides. But this works for me. You'll have to give some more clues/code if we want to get to the bottom of why it is not working for you.

Comment: I don't use text titles and bodies. I only have text items in my layout, so those aren't targeted by this search function.

Comment: Ok. I'm about to update the answer to include just text items. It would really help if you would give more information about 1) how your project is structured and 2) what code you've tried.

Comment: I have an excel spreadsheet with 6 entries per row. I have to insert these values into a keynote template which I have entered value placeholders into (e.g. ADDRESS, NAME, etc.). I want to search/replace item 1-6 of the data in each row into a corresponding keynote presentation. Some of the data has multiple instances in the keynote presentation. So far, I've just used applescript to activate excel, enter keystrokes to move the selector to the next value, copy, return to keynote, search for that columns placeholder title, replace all, return to excel and repeat.

Comment: The other issue is that, apparently, I have to target specific text items. I'd rather do this globally using the built-in search/replace function, but I havent found a way to do that.

Comment: I'd be (somewhat) surprised if whatever version of Excel you have isn't "natively" script-able to allow you to script without using keystrokes. If you can avoid that, you should. Using the built-in AppleScript dictionary is superior. For examples, search this forum for "applescript" and "excel". See updated answer to target every text item.

Comment: (apologies for leaving debug display dialog line in new bit of code; just took that out)